# Unused variable portion in a route?

Tags: playframework-2.1

I'm using Play! Framework 2.1 (Java version). I have a route that will look something like this:

http://www.mydomain.com/games/52/super-mario-bros

The "super-mario-bros" part is arbitrary and only added there for SEO purposes. Only the 52 is needed which corresponds to the ID to get for that game.

The issue is that I can't seem to figure out a way to have an arbitrary value in a route. I currently have, in my conf/routes file:

```
GET       /games/:id/:title       controllers.Games.viewGame(id: Long, title: String)
```

This works but now I have to add a second parameter into my "viewGame" method inside my Games controller, which never gets used. I would much rather have a route that looks something like this:

```
GET       /games/:id/:arbitrary      controllers.Games.viewGame(id: Long)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Quite old but check this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/QTVC4zM4otI